# UISegmentedControl losing Control over it's appearance

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uisegmentedcontrol

I am developing an iPhone app, and have come across an issue that leaves me completely perplexed.

In the app, there is a normal UIView, which consists of a UISegmentedControl. This UISegmentedControl is not once called or looked at in the code, in fact, there is no IBOutlet whatsoever, it lives only on the Storyboard.

Every time I load the app on my phone, my segmented control looks like this:
[image]

However, to my dismay, after a certain yet to be found out mixture of using the app, putting it in the background, and then using it again, the segmented control turns into this:
[image]

I know I don't have much more information to provide as of yet, but it seems hard to give any sort of code when there isn't any to do with the UI of the segment.
What I can say is that my "Use AutoLayout" is switched off.

I hope one of you can provide me more insight on how to fix this, thanks.

Comment: Have you set `appearance` of segment on some other viewcontroller ?

Comment: I haven't, have searched throughout the code for any change of appearance, but did not find any.

Comment: there must be something that change the appearance of segment.

Comment: Sorry, may be I am getting confused. Do you want UI of segment controller like as previous one?

Comment: Yes, I want it like the previous one.